# Problem in connection string with escaping char

Tags: go, go-gorm

Im trying to develop my first API using Go, but at beginning I run into a problem.

```
str := "sqlserver://DESKTOP-AAAC9AC@SQLEXPRESS?database=GolangPlay"
dsn := strings.Replace(str, "@", `\`, -1)
fmt.Println("CS be like : " + dsn)
_, err := gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
```

My connection string must contains escaping tag '' (DESKTOP-AAAC9AC\SQLEXPRESS), so I thought that firstly I might in my str string replace escaping tag with @. So that later when calling the gorm function sqlserver.Open(string) replace the @ with escaping tag, but I dont understand why this function returns error with double backslash

- "failed to initialize database, got error parse "sqlserver://DESKTOP-AAAC9AC\SQLEXPRESS?database=GolangPlay": invalid character "\" in host name"

but my println returns that what exactly I want

- CS be like : sqlserver://DESKTOP-AAAC9AC\SQLEXPRESS?database=GolangPlay

Please explain why this is happening and help in solving it

Comment: did you try to use only the host name?